# ¿Como inicio mi programa de java?

Tags: java

Estoy empezando en java, y estoy intentando ejecutar un programa que imprima un texto. es este:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Yass");
    }
}
```

Pero me sale esto:

> C:Users/miusuario/Desktop/miusuario/testing.java:1: error: class Test is public, should be declared in a file called Test.java

Pero ahí está el problema: No se como hacer el archivo Test.java para correr el codigo

Comment: El mismo error te lo dice, cuando una clase es pública el archivo que contiene la clase debe de llamarse igual que la clase, solo cambia el nombre al archivo.

Comment: necesito saber como crear esa clase porfa

Comment: Asi como generaste el archivo java con un IDE, debes mantener igual el nombre de tu clase principal.

Comment: La clase ya está creada, el problema es el nombre del archivo, solo accede a la carpeta 'C:Users/miusuario/Desktop/miusuario/' desde tu explorador de archivos y cambia el nombre de testing.java a Test.java

Comment: Si estás usando NetBeans el nombre del archivo y el de la clase deberían coincidir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los archivos que contiene código Java, deben guardarse con el mismo nombre que el que declaras en su clase, de hecho eso es lo que te indica el error.

Entocnes tu archivo debe llamarse

```
Test.java
```

Asegurate de respetar el uso de mayúscula y minúsculas, posterior el código interno debe ser el mismo

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Yass");
    }
}
```

> Siempre debes tener presente que estes o no trabajando con un **IDE**
>   tu archivo `.java` debe tener el mismo nombre que utilices para
>   declarar tu clase

Comment: Pero quiero saber como crear esa clase

Comment: @GabrielMation la clase ya esta declarada de manera correcta, lo único que tienes mal es el nombre del archivo

Comment: a que te refieres?

Comment: que el código que escribe es correcto, tu único error por lo que no funciona el programa era por el no0mbre de archivo

Comment: voy a probar...

Comment: a que te refieres con el nombre del archivo

Comment: perdoname, pero como ya dije, soy nuevo en java

Comment: el archivo que creaste para escribir ese código que muestra el mensaje "Yass" lo guardaste con el nombre `testting.java` y el nombre de tu clase es `Test` dado lo cual va a fallar por que en Java se exige que guardes el nombre del archivo con el mismo nombre que tiene la clase, que si revisas en tu código dice `Test`

Comment: oh. Muchisimas gracias. Ya entendí

Comment: por favor no olvides puntuar la respuesta @GabrielMation

Comment: dice que debo esperar 2 minutos